# Change column data type across database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatypes, type-conversion

I have a bunch of tables with many columns of data type `ntext`. I wish to change all such columns in all tables of a particular database to `nvarchar(max)`, because of [planned deprecation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) *(EDIT: also because I can't use such columns with `DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY` etc.)*. Is it possible to accomplish this without using `ALTER TABLE` with `ALTER COLUMN` for each table manually?

I am using MS SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no magic or hand-waving here. It'd be great if synonyms, say, applied to types, but that is not the case. If you want to make these columns first-class citizens, you'll need to change the table. You can automate this to some degree, though I won't post code to help with this unless you specify what you mean exactly by "manually" and why you think this will be a significant burden you want to avoid.

To automate this, you could say:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'ALTER TABLE '
  + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]))
  + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME([object_id])) 
  + ' ALTER COLUMN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' NVARCHAR(MAX)'
  + CASE is_nullable WHEN 0 THEN ' NOT NULL;' ELSE ';' END
FROM sys.columns
WHERE system_type_id = 99;

PRINT @sql;

-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

That said, you probably don't want to use these columns with distinct / group by anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I mean manually, I mean looking at each table in the Object Explorer, noting down the columns with datatype `ntext`, and executing `ALTER TABLE foo ALTER COLUMN bar nvarchar(max)` over and over again. I wish to avoid unnecessary manual labor if possible.

Comment: Automating the process will also hopefully ensure I don't do mistakes or miss/skip any columns.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show one way to automate this. The reason it is `PRINT` is so that you can preview the output and/or run commands individually. Just note that `PRINT` has a character limitation so you might observe the output looks truncated (the command itself is not).

Answer (score 0):

No, if you want to alter the column type you're going to have to use an ALTER COLUMN statement. Well, that's not true - you can drop the table and recreate it - but ALTER COLUMN is clearly superior :)